# RStudio yellow function snippet keyboard shortcut

Tags: rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

The RStudio snippets are very useful. However, they disappear once I start writing parameters. Is there any keyboard shortcut to bring them up again while writing the parameters of the function?

[image: Yellow parameter snippet]

Comment: the information is coming from the help page, you can just run `?fn()` to return the help page of the function in the help pane.

Comment: Yes @Phil, I can run ```help(function_name)``` but I would like to just load again the snippet to check out some parameters and keep writing on that line. Maybe it is not possible. Just wondering if it is.